# Adding localhost as a remote scope to my Bit.dev project returns a permission denied error

Tags: bit.dev

I'd like to add a local scope server as a remote scope to my project. However, when I run `bit remote add "http://localhost:3001"` I get a `error: permission to scope "" (http://localhost:3001) was denied` along with a troubleshoot url that redirects me to the Bit homepage.

I'm running bit version 0.0.779, and work within a company proxy.

#### Setting up and running my local scope

Following [these](https://bit.dev/docs/scope/creating-scopes) bare scope directions I do the following:

```
mkdir my-scope
cd my-scope
bit init --bare

bit start --port localhost:3001
```

#### Adding remote scope

In an existing, local react project I do the following:

```
bit init
bit add /path/to/my/compnent

bit remote add http://localhost:3001
```

#### Problem

Running `bit remote add http:localhost:3001` returns:

```
error: permission to scope "" (http://localhost:3001) was denied
see troubleshooting at https://legacy-docs.bit.dev/docs/setup-authentication#authentication-issues
```

Does anyone know why I might be getting denied from setting localhost as my remote scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the docker container to simplify the process of hosting scopes.
see details here - https://bit.dev/docs/scope/running-a-scope-server

regardless, it seems that the issue is just a typo, as you forgot to set `//` in the host url parameter of your command.

Comment: Thanks for the link to hosting scopes. Super appreciate you catching my error!